# How to deal (delete rows) with SQL Error (1062): Duplicate entry on UNIQUE column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a column declared as UNIQUE filled with human names:

```
Mary
John
Michel
&Mary
Kevin
```

I want to remove some characters from name column so I run a query like:

```
UPDATE db_name SET name = replace(name, '&', '')
```

But this query will fail with:

> SQL Error (1062): Duplicate entry 'Mary' for key 'name'

Is there a way to delete the row '&Mary' ONLY IF 'Mary' exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax (provided you are using MySQL) during `UPDATE`.</strike>

Use `UPDATE IGNORE`.

There's a neat trick you may find useful below:

http://leo.steamr.com/2011/09/mysql-update-on-duplicate-key-delete-work-around/

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is a feature of  MySQL's `INSERT` syntax, [not `UPDATE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

this query will delete row '&Mary' if a field exists with name = 'Mary'

```
delete from db_name 
where name= '&Mary' AND 
EXISTS(
       select 1 from db_name 
       where name = 'Mary'
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an `INNER JOIN` on the table against itself which concatenates an `&` onto the front of each name, you can perform a `DELETE` which identifies and removes the matches.  Following this deletion, it is then safe to run the `replace(name, '&', '')` in an `UPDATE` query as you originally intended.

```
/* names_amp is an alias of the same table */
DELETE names_amp FROM names names_amp
  /* the joining condition adds an '&' to the everything in the main table
     in order to find those which match */
  JOIN names ON CONCAT('&', names.name) = names_amp.name
```

Here it is in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5832d/1

If you don't want to apply this to everyone, and only to `'Mary'` you may simply add a `WHERE` clause:

```
DELETE names_amp FROM names names_amp
  JOIN names ON CONCAT('&', names.name) = names_amp.name
WHERE names.name = 'Mary'
```

The proper syntax for deleting with a join is [explained in the MySQL `DELETE` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)